# A question about the proof of $(z_1z_2)^a=z_1^az_2^a$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> For $z_1,z_2\in \mathbb C$ if $\Im(z_1z_2)>0$ and $\Im(z_2)\ge 0$ prove that $(z_1z_2)^a=z_1^az_2^a$ , for $a$ is any **real**.

I proved it like this:

$z_1^az_2^a=\exp(a\log z_1)\exp(a\log z_2)=\exp(a(\log z_1+\log z_2))=\exp(a\log(z_1z_2))=(z_1z_2)^a$.

**But , where is the condition needed and why?**

Comment: What is $a$? Is it an integer? Is it a rational number? Is it a real number? Is it a complex number?

Comment: $a$ is real number...Though it is not given in the question..You can assume it as real..

Comment: Hint: look at $(-1)^{1/2}(-1)^{1/2}=i\times i = -1$ and $((-1)(-1))^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$

Comment: @ gammatester ) Yes..I saw it by example that the condition is needed...but when I am going to prove it then where it is needed ?

Comment: Generally you do  **not** have $\log(z_1 z_2)= \log(z_1)+\log( z_2)$

Comment: How do you know that $\log z_1 + \log z_2 = \log z_1z_2$?

Comment: Ok...where I use the condition ?

Comment: Which values (branches) of $\log$ are you using? The condition shall presumably ensure that you have $\log (z_1z_2) = \log z_1 + \log z_2$ for the chosen values. (But $\Im (z_2) \geq 0$ is problematic. For $\Im (z_2) > 0$, we could use the principal branch and be done, but any branch on a domain containing negative reals doesn't work as specified.)